# Error on creating ClusterRoleBinding with Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-modules, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I am getting this error when i apply my terraform configurations, I am not sure why this is happening.

```
│ Error: clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "test-psp-clusterrole" is forbidden: user "<GKE-Service-Account-Email>" (groups=["system:authenticated"]) 
is attempting to grant RBAC permissions not currently held:
│ {APIGroups:["policy"], Resources:["podsecuritypolicies"], ResourceNames:["test-psp"], Verbs:["use" "get" "list" "create" "delete" "update" "patch" "deletecollection"]}
```

**ClusterRoleBinding**

```
resource "kubernetes_cluster_role_binding" "psp-clusterrolebinding" {
  metadata {
    name = "test-psp-clusterrolebinding"
  }

  role_ref {
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind      = "ClusterRole"
    name      = "test-psp-clusterrole"
  }

  subject {
    kind      = "Group"
    name      = "system:serviceaccounts"
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
  }

  subject {
    kind      = "Group"
    name      = "system:authenticated"
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
  }

  subject {
    kind      = "User"
    name      = "GKE-service-account-email@project-domain.com" #(the service account email)
    api_group = ""
  }

  subject {
    kind      = "ServiceAccount"
    name      = "tf-test-sa" #(the service account name)
    api_group = ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the user/service account which is executing terraform code has PSP permission itself?

Comment: under the IAM account view on GCP, it has a role which has the rights to create clusterrole, this IAM account is also a service account in GCP  but permissions doesnt seem to have the roles that the IAM account has even though theyre the same, I'm confused

Comment: To create that ClusterRoleBinding, the caller SA must have the container.clusterRoleBindings.create permission. Only the OWNER and Kubernetes Engine Admin IAM Roles contain that permission (because it allows modification of access control on your GKE clusters), could you please confirm if the service account used by TF have the Owner role or Kubernetes Engine Admin role in IAM ?